# NGRX for non persisted data

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, uid

I'm starting with a new Angular project using the NGRX store. I'm trying to figure out how to use the store for non-persisted (nested) data.

For example when creating a new product with a collection of option which all have a collection of prices.

Usually, for persisted data, I would use the ID's to lookup the entities and mutate the changes into the state. However for non-persisted data I do not yet have ID's from the database.

I am now at the point of choosing between using front-end generated uid's or not, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this without uid's. Using uid's will have major impact on how the rest of the application will behave so I would rather find a solution without the need for this.

Is there any other way of doing this?

p.s. Storing 'empty' entities (to recieve proper PK's) in advance is no option for us because we have multiple other projects relying on the same backend.

Comment: Do you have a lot of nested objects?

Comment: yes, we're dealing with many nested structures. That's why this is a core  decision to make right now, before building the rest of the application.

Comment: Ok because I have a huge application which uses MongoDB as backend which generates an `_id` property on the top level object, and then everything that is nested inside only has an `id` property. So I'm using the `id` property to find and perform actions on all the nested objects. It works well for me so I don't see any problems for you guys to do the same. Only part that is a pain in the ass is to actually write all the necessary recursive functions for all possible actions that there are.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I disagree. You can use normalizr to flatten the whole model save to store and denormalise as required. Than front end updates are in one place only and don't require going through the nest